# how to check md5hash of a directory and compare that with a file that contains the hash of all the files sent to a destination directory

Tags: linux, hash

My goal is to check which files I have copied over to the destination directory and which files I have not, by creating a file that will store the hash of the files that I have copied to the destination directory. If the hash of the source directory does not match the hashes inside the a file that contain all the hashes of the file that's been copied over, then copy the file to the destination directory and add the new hash to the file that contains all the hash of files that's been copied to the destination directory.

src_dir=/source_directory
dest_dir=/destination_directory
hashofall=text file that stored the hash of all the files that's been copied over to $dest_dir

md5hash $src_dir/* #compare this hash with $hashofall
if match don't copy the file over to $src_dir
if does not match copy the file over to $dest_dir and store md5hash to $hashofall of the ones that just copied over in linux.

purpose of this is to check which of the new files that I have not copied over.

Comment: Take a look at `rsync`, which may already do what you want!

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score -1):

You can give a try to simple diff dir1 dir2 ,but if for any case it's not enough for you, try something like this:

```
hashes_src=$(cd $srcDir ; find  . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort)
hashes_src=$(cd $dstDir ; find  . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort)
comm -23 <(echo $hashes_src) <(echo hashes_dst)
```